# Code Coveragein Separate Solutions

Tags: mbunit, ncrunch

(I posted this question on NCrunch forum but I've not received a response in 3 days.)

I just downloaded, installed, and enabled NCrunch.

I'm using: VS 2012, Gallio, MbUnit.

I've a main solution with several projects. At this point I want to test code in one key project in the main solution. I'll want to test code in the other projects at some future time.

I've a second separate test solution with the test code. In the test solution I added a reference to the project DLL in the main solution.

I enabled NCrunch in the test solution and then successfully ran the tests in the test solution. I see the markers on the test code lines.

I want to see code coverage information for the project code in my main solution.

Is there a way to do that?

Ed

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with ncrunch, at least I've never seen a way.

In order to calculate the code coverage you'll have to create a solution which has your test code and your main code in it. To be honest this a normal situation. How can you efficiently write tests and new code if they are not in the same solution?

you could either create a new solution with both projects in it or just add the main project to the test solution, then keep the main solution to build just the main dll and not the test ones.